# How do I make a button full height of the parent container and right-aligned?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using `Bootstrap` and I want add a button at right of a bar that looks like `<input-group-addon>`. To be specific, full height and locates at right most.

I've tried `height: 100%` but the button styles super high.

this is part of my code: https://plnkr.co/edit/lK8vt0wT1xDesuOZW8vU?p=preview

this is what I m looking for [image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try absolutely positioning your button:

```css
.my-heading {
  position: relative;
}

.btn.my-btn {
  position:absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading my-heading">Assist Panel<button class="my-btn btn"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></button></div>
    <div class="panel-body"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, and I noticed that you removed three round corners, that helps.

Answer (score 2):

The parent needs `position:relative`.
Then you can position the button absolutely in the corner with `height:100%`

```css
.panel-heading{
  position:relative;
}

button.btn{
  float: none;
  margin-right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Assist Panel<button style="float:right;margin-right:0;" class="btn" onclick="assist_close()"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></button></div>
      <div class="panel-body"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: there is some hidden styling being applied by bootstrap without which this doesn't seem to work. i have narrowed it down to the panel-heading having a padding of 10px.

Answer (score 1):

**Using Position Property**

```css
.panel-heading{
  position: relative;
}
button.btn{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  border-radius: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Assist Panel<button class="btn" onclick="assist_close()"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></button></div>
      <div class="panel-body"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but I want the button to have full height as the container like the image shows, is that possible?

Comment: @Zanecat , you need to change the position. I think its answered already by Miro.

Answer (score 0):

By using display flex on the parent panel you could set the panel heading and the button next to each other and then they will naturally have the same height. Then would just need to adjust to panel-heading width.

```css
.panel{
  display: flex;
}

.panel-heading {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Assist Panel</div>
      <button class="btn" onclick="assist_close()"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></button>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```